# Want to create a Question/ Answer site, So what should I read to build such a site?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal, joomla

I am new to website building and want to create a site which have following features:

1. People should be able to post new questions.
2. Should be able to comment on the already provided questions (Providing Answer is equal to providing comments.)
3. Should be able to categorize various questions.

I am planning to go on Open source side: Using PHP/APACHE/MYSQL/LINUX.

I am not sure what all things i should read Like CMS (Drupal/Joomla etc.)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The easiest would be to read the [FAQ on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). In other words, just suggest a new SO site instead of trying to build your own. Especially if you are new to web development.

Comment: I would like to develop something like www.allinterview.com or www.careercup.com etc. I just need a guideline to go with and what all i need to read to make a site like these mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to answer all your questions in one answer.

If you're really new to php, I doub't you should dive in a CMS.

I recomend you to split-up your questions in to smaller ones and start googling and coding.

- People should ble able to post

  - Choosing a database?
  - Adding entries to a table?
  - Registering users?
- Commenting

  - Again, adding to database
  - Retreiving from database
  - Displaying results
- Categories

  - Database architecture
  - Normalazing database
  - Again, adding and retreivieng from database

..and so on.

This would be ok if you're doing it for practice, not for real life product.

If you're looking for a quality product, you should go for a cms.

Comment: Yes I am looking for quality stuff , want to add a lot of info that i gather in all my software career, but also i want the site to auto grow so that I can further grow it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several open-source packages you could use. Or you could go over to http://area51.stackexchange.com/ and see if any of the 566 sites in development would do what you want.

Some open-source question-and-answer packages:

- OSQA - http://www.osqa.net/ (Django / Python)
- AskBot - http://askbot.org/ (Django / Python)
- Shapado - http://shapado.com/ (Ruby/Rails)
- Question2Answer -  (see that dot org)- (PHP)

Answer (score 1):

OSQA is open source stackoverflow.com clone, running on Django and Python

http://www.osqa.net/

(just replace one P in your LAMP stack with another P :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to have a forum in PHP for question/answer, I recommend you take a look at [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/). You may also take a look at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_(PHP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_%28PHP%29)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a database to store questions, comments and categories
2. Design a web interface using HTML, CSS and JavaScript
3. Use PHP to create a back-end and connect the web interface to the database
4. Use Apache to serve the web pages
5. Use Linux as the operating system
6. Create a login and registration system to allow users to post questions, comments and categorize questions
7. Utilize security measures to protect the website from malicious activities
8. Implement a search feature to allow users to easily search for questions and comments
9. Implement a notification system to alert users when someone comments on their questions or posts
10. Add social media integration to allow users to share questions and comments on their social media profiles
11. Create an administration page to allow admins to manage user accounts, questions, comments and categories
12. Implement an analytics system to measure user engagement with the website and track data about user activity